# Try oracle connection if first or second connection attempt failed in Python

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port,sid)

for c in range(1,4):

try:

    db = cx_Oracle.connect(username,password, dsn_tns)

    break

except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:

    continue
```

** Hi, Can I use the code above to attempt second or third connection if first attempt for connection failed (raise error exception) ?

Comment: Hi @Zainuddin and welcome to stackoverflow. I'm not sure about the issue you're having, are you getting a specific error message when running the code or are you asking whether it is acceptable/good practice to attempt re-connecting to the database?

Comment: Hi @Stig, in case first attempt to connect the database is failed, due to error, the code will attempt the second trial. And if the second try failed, the code will attempt the third try. Is it the good practise to write code like this, just to ensure connection is established. –

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm not an expert on Python 2.7 but in general it depends on what type of error you get from the failed connection and what the requirements are for your app regarding uptime/stability. E.g. trying to write data into a column not present in the database would produce a very consistent error, where as not being able to connect to the database (if it happens in an inconsistent matter) is usually network-related and should be handled outside your Python app. In short I would focus on logging the error message until I was sure what the root cause is.